# How to fix "pods is not balanced" in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, infrastructure

Pods doesn't balance in node pool. why doesn't spread to each node?

I have 9 instance in 1 node pool. In the past, I’ve tried add to 12 instance. Pods doesn't balance.

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b0ZY.png)
Would like to know if there is any solution that can help solve this problem and used 9 instance in 1 node pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pods are scheduled to run on nodes by the kube-scheduler. And once they are scheduled, they are not rescheduled unless they are removed.

So if you add more nodes, the already running pods won't reschedule.

There is a project in incubator that solves exactly this problem.

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/descheduler

> Scheduling in Kubernetes is the process of binding pending pods to
>   nodes, and is performed by a component of Kubernetes called
>   kube-scheduler. The scheduler's decisions, whether or where a pod can
>   or can not be scheduled, are guided by its configurable policy which
>   comprises of set of rules, called predicates and priorities. The
>   scheduler's decisions are influenced by its view of a Kubernetes
>   cluster at that point of time when a new pod appears first time for
>   scheduling. As Kubernetes clusters are very dynamic and their state
>   change over time, there may be desired to move already running pods to
>   some other nodes for various reasons:
>
> - Some nodes are under or over utilized.
> - The original scheduling decision does not hold true any more, as taints or labels are added to or removed from nodes, pod/node
>     affinity requirements are not satisfied any more.
> - Some nodes failed and their pods moved to other nodes.
> - New nodes are added to clusters.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [inter-pod anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity-beta-feature). This feature allows you to constrain where your pods should not be scheduled based on the labels of the pods running on a node. In your case, given your app has label `app-label`, you can use it to ensure pods do not get scheduled on nodes that have pods with the label `app-label`. For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      label-key: label-value
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        label-key: label-value
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: label-key
                operator: In
                values:
                - label-value
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
...
```

PS: If you use `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`, you can have at most as many pods as you have nodes. If you expect to have more pods than nodes available, you will have to use `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`, which makes antiaffinity be a preference, rather than an obligation.